# Load Dynamic content based on raido button input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 boxes, a,b,c,d and if I user picks box a I want it to do the following;

pick image a load content 1

pick image b load content 2

pick image c load content 3

pick image d load content 4

I want all of the content that might be loaded to be hidden until the radio button is clicked. So far it is all hidden but when the radio button is clicked no content loads.

Thanks!

```
<div id="framework">
    <div class="element">
        <img style="float:left;" src="img/left.png" />
        <img style="padding-left:25px; float:left;" src="img/right.png" />
        <img style="padding-left:25px; float:left;" src="img/both.png" />
        <img style="padding-left:25px; float:left;" src="img/without.png" />
    </div>
    <form class="actions">
        <div style="clearfix:none;" class="confirm">
            <input type="radio" id="frame_left" name="framework">
        </div>
        <div style="clearfix:none;" class="confirma">
            <input type="radio" id="frame_right" name="framework">
        </div>
        <div style="clearfix:none;" class="confirmb">
            <input type="radio" id="frame_both" name="framework">
        </div>
        <div style="clearfix:none;" class="confirmc">
            <input type="radio" id="frame_without" name="framework">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // do your checks of the radio buttons here and show/hide what you want to
        $("#navLeft").hide();
        $("#navRight").hide();
        if ($("#frame_left:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#navLeft").hide();
        }

        // add functionality for the onclicks here
        $("#frame_left").click(function() {
            $("#navleft").show();
        });

        $("#frame_right").click(function() {
            $("#navRight").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<img id="navLeft" src="img/left.png" />
<img id="navRight" src="img/right.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your existing code.

Comment: see .click() for radio button and and put a trigger on that

Comment: Sorry I swear I posted my code in my mistake thanks!

Comment: where or what is your content?

Comment: content showing is in the elements div, radio buttons are in the actions form, and under the javascript is the content I want to show/hide via the radio buttons

Comment: I have got it to work but when you click off the radio button it doesn't high the content again how would you do that? So all the content is hidden click a box to show the content but when you click off that radio button it still shows :(

Answer (score 1):

`navLeft`(with CamelCase) is the ID of your DIV but you're using `navleft`(without Camelcase) in your Script.

You're hiding `navRight` and if you click `frame_right` your JS will hide `navRight` again? That's not logical, or?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a switch statement and hide the content elements by default with css.
[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9MnT/2/). Didn't know what you mean with `frame_without`. Maybe just to display nothing, like it is now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="framework"]').change(function() {
    $('#navLeft, #navRight').hide();

    switch($('input[name="framework"]:checked').attr('id')) {
        case "frame_left":
           $("#navLeft").show();
            break;
        case "frame_right":
            $("#navRight").show();
            break;
        case "frame_both":
           $("#navLeft, #navRight").show();
            break;
         case "frame_without":
            //Dont know what here should happen
            break;
    }
});
});
```

The css to hide the content:

```
#navLeft, #navRight {
    display: none;
}
```